# kafka produce message when condition is met in all messages having eventTime between ts to ts -1 min

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams

I want process kafka messages where I receive data in non linear format considering eventTime
I want to produce message to new topic, after receiving  message in below JSON format and if I get a condition that all the message between `eventTime` to `eventTime - 1min` met a condition of `abs(valueA - ValueB) > 10`

```
"UserID":222,"eventTime":04-03-2024 12:13:48,"ValueA":90,"ValueB":71
"UserID":222,"eventTime":04-03-2024 12:13:44,"ValueA":94,"ValueB":66
"UserID":222,"eventTime":04-03-2024 12:13:47,"ValueA":92,"ValueB":65
"UserID":222,"eventTime":04-03-2024 12:13:46,"ValueA":99,"ValueB":65
"UserID":222,"eventTime":04-03-2024 12:13:45,"ValueA":80,"ValueB":70
```

Please suggest any client library / stream processing framework for this problems

I tried redis cacheing mechanism but data is not sorted with eventTime key

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a fairly standard use-case for Flink's built-in [Windowing](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/) functionality, which supports varying types of pre-built windowing strategies (tumbling, sliding, sessions, custom, etc.) as well as fine-grained control over evaluations within the windows such that you can control what is emitted from them.

It also supports both keyed and unkeyed depending on your needs (especially when with regards to parallel processing, such as if you needed to perform this same operator at the "user" level instead of against a larger population.

This seems like a situation where you might consider something like:

- Designate your `eventTime` as the property used for windowing purposes
- Potentially key your stream by your user `UserId`
- Define a one minute tumbling window (or a custom window)
- Define a stateful windowing transformation that would allow you to evaluate your emission constraints and determine if you need to emit your signal

There's quite a few ways to accomplish this depending on your needs, but Flink is certainly a capable tool for it.